# I converted a react js app using ionic/capacitor and when launching on device, it keeps trying to load assets from server?

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

Initially i loaded them from localhost server just to run the app and when I removed it from capacitor.config.json file, I keep getting those errors. `Unable to open asset URL: http://localhost/...` The thing is assets got bundled in " android/app/src/main/assets/public" even though i sepicified webDir: "build". I trying changing the path of webDir to that I got: "Could not find the web assets directory: .\android\app\src\main\assets\public. Please create it and make sure it has an index.html file. You can change the path of this directory in capacitor.config.json "

i used these:

```
{
  "appId": "",
  "appName": "",
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "android/app/src/main/assets/public"
}
```

assets don't get generated in build older even when i use this

```
{
  "appId": "",
  "appName": "",
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "build"
}
```

So my app doesn't run it just goes blank, the existing react app is already deployed on gh-pages so when I put back server to the link of deployment it works just fine but I don't wanna do that since I'm gonna upload it on google play store

gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    namespace ""
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```